# Performance of terms aggregation

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, aggregation

I have an index with 10,000,000 documents in it. Elasticsearch is configured to use 5 shards, no replicas.

Each document has two fields:

1. Field `tags`, containing three tags. There are currently 82 user-defined tags in my index.
2. Field `singleTag`, containing only one tag out of the same set of 82 possible values. (this field is used for comparison only)

I want to query the first ten tags (according to alphabetical order). This takes around 300ms for field `tags` (and only takes 150ms for field `singleTag`). How can I increase the performance of this query?

A sample document:

```
{
    "tags": ["player", "ballsports", "goals"],
    "singleTag": "football"
}
```

My index definition:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": "5",
    "number_of_replicas": "0"
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "issue": {
      "properties": {
        "tags": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "singleTag": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The current (too slow) query:

```
{
    "size" : 0,
    "aggregations" : {
        "tagsAggregation" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "tags",
                "size" : 10,
                "order" : {
                    "_term" : "asc"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm currently using Elasticsearch 2.4.4 but solutions including Elasticsearch 5 are also welcome. The performance in Elasticsearch 5 is similar for the first request, but caching is much better.

Comment: Since the `singleTag` field has a lower cardinality (only one tag vs 1+ in the `tags` field), it can be a reason why it runs faster.

Comment: @Val Absolutely! I hope this gives a valueable hint to someone, who answers this question. But I cannot drop the 1+ cardinality for functional requirements.

Comment: Which version of ES do you run?

Comment: Docs says "the default shard_size is a multiple of the size parameter which is dependant on the number of shards", but in this case you'd get exact results by setting `shard_size` to 10 as well. Please let me know if this speeds up things, but anyway I think something else sub-optimal is going on. Is disk IO at zero?

Comment: @NikoNyrh actually in my tests, 10 shards made it a bit better, but no "break-through".

Comment: You could also try different execution hints, but I must say that ES isn't ideal for this kind of "global" aggregation. It would 
be trivial to store this set of 100 user-defined tags to some other DB engine. Or 300 ms shouldn't be too bad if you cache the result. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-execution-hint

Comment: @NikoNyrh execution hints `map` and `global_ordinals_low_cardinality` had similar performance (but not better as before); `global_ordinals` and `global_ordinals_hash` were much slower (>1000ms).

Comment: I tried *force merging*, but it did not help.

Comment: So tu sum it up: you're saying that the cardinality of your tags is 82, i.e. you have only 82 different tags in both fields. I'm a bit suprised by the time it takes with such a low cardinality. What hardware are you running this on?

Comment: @Val I'm running on an 2.7 GHz i5 8GB ram iMac, using an external ssd harddrive.

Comment: Have you tried to relocate your data on your internal harddrive and see if there's any difference? Very easy to test. I wouldn't bet much on performance measured on an external harddrive.

Comment: @slartidan have you seen my latest comment?